# How to remove punctuation from tokens, when quanteda tokenizes at sentence level?

Tags: r, nlp, token, quanteda

It is my ultimate goal to select some sentences from a corpus which match a certain pattern & perform a sentiment analysis upon these selected cutouts from the corpus. I am trying to do all of that with a current version of quanteda in R.

I noticed that `remove_punctuation` does not remove punctuation when `tokens` is applied at the sentence-level (`what = "sentence"`). When decomposing the selected sentence-tokens to word-tokens for the sentiment analysis, the word-tokens will contain punctuation such as "," or ".". Dictionaries are then no longer able to match on these tokens. Reproducible example:

```
mypattern <- c("country", "honor")
#
txt <- c(wash1 <- "Fellow citizens, I am again called upon by the voice of my country to execute the functions of its Chief Magistrate.",
         wash2 <- "When the occasion proper for it shall arrive, I shall endeavor to express the high sense I entertain of this distinguished honor.", 
         blind <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.")
#
toks <- tokens_select(tokens(txt, what = "sentence", remove_punct = TRUE), 
                             pattern = paste0(mypattern, collapse = "|"), 
                             valuetype = "regex", 
                             selection = "keep")
#
toks
```

For instance, the tokens in `toks` contain "citizens," or "arrive,". I thought about splitting the tokens back to word-tokens by `tokens_split(toks, separator = " ")` but `separator` does allow one input parameter only.

Is there a way to remove the punctuation from the sentences when tokenizing at the sentence-level?

Comment: possible solution
`toks2 <- tokens_split(toks, separator = "\\b", valuetype = "regex")`
`toks3 <- tokens_remove(toks2, "[[:punct:]]", valuetype = "regex")`
`toks4 <- tokens_remove(toks3, "\\p{Z}", valuetype = "regex")`
`toks4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to go about your goal, which consists of performing sentiment analysis on just sentences from documents containing your target pattern.  You can do this by first reshaping your corpus into sentences, then tokenising them, then using `tokens_select()` with the `window` argument to select only those documents containing the pattern.  In this case you will set a window so large that it will include the entire sentence.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.1
#> Unicode version: 13.0
#> ICU version: 67.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

txt <- c("Fellow citizens, I am again called upon by the voice of my country to execute the functions of its Chief Magistrate.
          When the occasion proper for it shall arrive, I shall endeavor to express the high sense I entertain of this distinguished honor.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.")
corp <- corpus(txt)

corp_sent <- corpus_reshape(corp, to = "sentences")
corp_sent
#> Corpus consisting of 3 documents.
#> text1.1 :
#> "Fellow citizens, I am again called upon by the voice of my c..."
#> 
#> text1.2 :
#> "When the occasion proper for it shall arrive, I shall endeav..."
#> 
#> text1.3 :
#> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."

# sentiment on just the documents with the pattern
mypattern <- c("country", "honor")
toks <- tokens(corp_sent) %>%
  tokens_select(pattern = mypattern, window = 10000000)
toks
#> Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
#> text1.1 :
#>  [1] "Fellow"   "citizens" ","        "I"        "am"       "again"   
#>  [7] "called"   "upon"     "by"       "the"      "voice"    "of"      
#> [ ... and 11 more ]
#> 
#> text1.2 :
#>  [1] "When"     "the"      "occasion" "proper"   "for"      "it"      
#>  [7] "shall"    "arrive"   ","        "I"        "shall"    "endeavor"
#> [ ... and 12 more ]
#> 
#> text1.3 :
#> character(0)

# now perform sentiment analysis on the selected tokens
tokens_lookup(toks, dictionary = data_dictionary_LSD2015) %>%
  dfm()
#> Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 4 features (91.67% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>          features
#> docs      negative positive neg_positive neg_negative
#>   text1.1        0        0            0            0
#>   text1.2        0        5            0            0
#>   text1.3        0        0            0            0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that if you to exclude the sentences that were empty, just use `dfm_subset(dfmat, nfeat(dfmat) > 0)` where `dfmat` is your saved output sentiment analysis dfm.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Will be somewaht difficult if one includes a window of sentences around a sentence that matches a pattern. Additionally, toks will contain "," and "." in `ntoken(tok)` which slightly biases a sentiment calculation (frac{P-N}{T}) in the denominator. btw, would be a nice addition to `tokens_lookup` function if it included `ntoken`. will mark as solved!